# Get only values from rows and associations with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize, MySQL and Node to write a web application.

For most of my DB needs, I usually do some verification, then fetch my models (eagerly with associations) and send them back to the client, almost always as-is (at least, up to now).

I wrote a little utility function `getValuesFromRows` to extract the values from a returned row array:

```
getValuesFromRows: function(rows, valuesProp) {
    // get POD (plain old data) values
    valuesProp = valuesProp || 'values';
    if (rows instanceof Array) {
        var allValues = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
            allValues[i] = rows[i][valuesProp];
        }
        return allValues;
    }
    else if (rows) {
        // only one object
        return rows[valuesProp];
    }
    return null;
}

// ...

...findAll(...)...complete(function(err, rows) {
     var allValues = getValuesFromRows(rows);
     sendToClient(errToString(err, user), allValues);
});
```

However, I am adding more and more complex relations to my DB models. As a result, I get more associations that I have to fetch. Now, I don't only have to call above function to get the `values` from each row, but also I need more complicated utilities to get the `values` from all included (eagerly loaded) associations. Is there a way to only get values from Sequelize queries (and not the Sequelize model instance) that also includes all associated values from the instance?

Else, I would have to manually "get all `values` from each `Project` and add one item to that `values` object for the `values` property of each entry of `Project.members`" (for example). Note that things get worse fast if you nest associations (e.g. members have `tasks` and `tasks` have this and that etc.).

I am guessing that I have to write such utility myself?

Comment: Currently `.get()` will return all values of the toplevel object but return instances for the included objects, it's in the works to provide a easy way to get just a plain object when calling `.get()` (it will probably be the default unless you're doing `.get(key)`).

As a temporary hack you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(instance))` to get a POJO.

Comment: @MickHansen 1. `findAll` returns an array. You are saying that array has an added `get()` method? 2. Stringifying the entire complex object will include all kinds of things that you don't want in there. It is not desirable at all. I will wait and hope for a more complete solution :)

Comment: no the array is just an array, but each instance has a `.get()`. No stringifying will not, it uses `toJSON` which maps to `get()` which gives you the base values.

Comment: I don't get it. I can already get the POD values by simply getting the `values` property. Why use `get()` or JSON?

Comment: `values` simply maps to `get`, and no `get()` will give you the included instances aswell, so they will have more properties than just values (if you have used prefetching).

Comment: @MickHansen Yeah, it makes no sense. I expected, if I use `get()` (or `values`, or `dataValues`), that it's all POD, but the included relation objects are non-POD sequelize model instances. That is pretty sad.

Comment: No software is perfect. Provide a pull request or voice your support on the existing feature request on GH.

Comment: @MickHansen Thank you for your help and support! I came up with a solution below. Feel free to check it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple solution to my problem, by extending my existing POD converting function above with a recursion into all `include`'d associations of the query. The Solution works with `find`, `findAll`, `all` and possibly other operations with non-trivial results.

**Code**

```
/**
 * Get POD (plain old data) values from Sequelize results.
 *
 * @param rows The result object or array from a Sequelize query's `success` or `complete` operation.
 * @param associations The `include` parameter of the Sequelize query.
 */
getValuesFromRows: function(rows, associations) {
    // get POD (plain old data) values
    var values;
    if (rows instanceof Array) {
        // call this method on every element of the given array of rows
        values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
            // recurse
            values[i] = this.getValuesFromRows(rows[i], associations);
        }
    }
    else if (rows) {
        // only one row
        values = rows.dataValues;

        // get values from associated rows
        if (values && associations) {
            for (var i = 0; i < associations.length; ++i) {
                var association = associations[i];
                var propName = association.as;

                // recurse
                values[propName] = this.getValuesFromRows(values[propName], association.include);
            };
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

**Example**

```
var postAssociations = [
// poster association
{
    model: User,
    as: 'author'
},

// comments association
{
    model: Comment,
    as: 'comments',
    include: [
    {
        // author association
        model: User,
        as: 'author'
    }
    ]
}
];

// ...

var query = {
    where: ...
    include: postAssociations;
};

// query post data from DB
return Post.findAll(query)

// convert Sequelize result to POD
.then(function(posts) {
    return getValuesFromRows(posts, postAssociations);
})

// send POD back to client
.then(client.sendPosts);
```

In the above example, `client.sendPosts` receives an array. Each entry of the array will have properties `author` and `comments`. Each comment in the `comments` array will also have an `author` property. The entire array only contains POD (plain old data).